# IAccessible deisgn questions: child objects, thread safety, and header rows/comctl32.dll header controls, and a few other questions on top of that

Tags: winapi, com, thread-safety, custom-controls, accessibility

So before I continue developing my accessible table I read [this, on exposing data tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971325) and the general MSAA documentation and I want to clear up a few things before I actually go ahead and write out this implementation, just so I can get everything *just* right.

For the record, this table is strictly owner-data and is row-based, where a given row can be selected, and a single cell within this row can be focused. Otherwise it behaves similarly to a listview control, but is not one, so I'm not going to try to take advantage of its accessibility features. In particular, any column can contain text, images, or checkboxes (and I might add more features); there might be background colors and text editability in the future as well. All cells in a given column have one of these types. The type will not change during runtime.

I am choosing to use MSAA because I still need Windows XP support, and I would rather not require developers and end users to have both SP3 and the .net framework together, which UI Automation seems to require (and even if the SP3 part is wrong, the "is not standalone/does not come out of the box with the OS" part still makes me uneasy about implementing that).

1. Is it process-safe/thread-safe to call my internal control functions within the accessible object method implementations, or should I use `WM_USER` messages to make sure everything happens all on one thread of one process? (In addition, would my error handling/debugging traps be run in the client or in the server in either case?)
2. From what I can gather, I need to build a three-level IAccessible hierarchy: the table itself on top, followed by each row, followed by each cell in the row. However, the various IAccessible methods that take a child object only take a `VT_I4` `VARIANT` to specify the child. Does this mean I'm going to have to create an IAccessible for each row as well, or for each cell as well, or something else? Should I have a standard accessible object for each of these? Can they share? And what about `NotifyWinEvent()`; how would I indicate that a given cell has changed? Or should I say the whole row has changed...?
3. If the answer to question 2 is "yes", I'm going to wind up with a lot of IAccessible objects that need to be notified when the table control is destroyed. If the answer to question 1 is "it is not thread-safe", then is it safe to hold a lock in my IAccessible methods whenever I access my table control and have that hold the lock when it's time to invalidate all those IAccessibles? Or should I investigate some other approach? I see talk on MSDN of "proxy objects" but I'm not really following how that would help... especially if I need to make lots of IAccessibles.
4. From what I can gather I need to return (number of rows) + 1 rows in my table's `get_accChildCount()` method, with the first row being full of column header cells. But I'm not using a custom header control; I'm using the standard comctl32.dll header control. Should I hide that control and construct my column headers according to the Exposing Data Tables document or should I relegate the first row to the header control? I don't see a way to do both... (I do not have row headers, so will not be implementing that.) Columns can be user-resized, but may be automatically sized to fit until the user first does so (maybe).
5. Is it safe to relegate IDispatch methods to the window handle's standard accessible object? Even in the case of the row and cell IAccessibles? Or will the standard accessible object's IDispatch not call **my** IAccessible methods?
6. What should `accDoDefaultAction()` do for a checkbox cell, toggle the checkbox state? And for an editable text cell, should it enter editing mode?

Thanks. (Hoping none of this sounds dumb...)

**UPDATE** 6 January 2015

I changed the wording of some of the paragraphs above and have one more question:

7. How do I correctly check for errors from `LresultFromObject()`, by casting to an `HRESULT` and checking that, or by comparing a signed version of the `LRESULT` value and seeing if it's less than zero, or something else?

Comment: I'd say for 1, that it's "thread-safe", because accessibility objects will (should?) live in a STA.  However, if you need atomic operations, such as read-modify-write, then it's not safe, as you can't stop the STA from processing other method calls between your own.  STAs process inter-apartment calls in Windows message loops and they allow re-entrant calls (i.e. an inter-apartment call from the STA will run a loop that processes incoming inter-apartment method calls).

Comment: @PauloMadeira thanks for the reply. This is very late, but: I thought I understood this the first time I read it but now I'm not so sure, so just to confirm: does this mean that an STA call can occur *during* another STA call when I'm NOT pumping messages (for example, in a `WM_PAINT` handler)? And what about `SendMessage()` to a window in the same thread? I ask this because I wonder if there would be a race to invalidate all accessible objects once my control is destroyed (`case WM_DESTROY: for each accessible object { invalidate it so future calls return RPC_E_DISCONNECTED }`). Thanks again!

Comment: An incoming call to the STA may occur during an outgoing call from the STA, because the way COM awaits for the outgoing call's response is by pumping messages.  This happens even if you're handling a queued message (e.g. `PostMessage).  If you're handling e.g. `WM_PAINT` and you don't pump messages (explicitly or by making remote COM calls), you won't have this kind of reentrancy.  If you're handling a non-queued message (e.g. `SendMessage`), I think COM forbids you from making remote calls that are not `input_sync`, so there won't be an implicit modal loop.

Comment: You can implement `IMessageFilter` to control common STA reentrancy.

Comment: Okay, so it seems to me that there's no issue between any message and accessible calls, assuming the `WM_DESTROY` that a `DestroyWindow()` on the hwnd itself or of its parent window sends also count as a pumped message. Thanks again!

Comment: The documentation says "The function sends WM_DESTROY...", so be careful to call only objects in the same apartment, or better yet, your own objects only.